# Matblazor component attributes: complex content

Tags: binding, blazor, matblazor

I am trying to make a button that is disabled if a certain condition is false. For a regular button this works:

```
<button @disabled="!IsReady">Click me</button>
@code
{
    public bool IsReady { get; set; }
}
```

I am using MatBlazor library that has `MatButton` version of `button`:

```
<MatButton Disabled="@!IsReady">Click me</MatButton>
```

The latter does't work: it gives the following error:

> Component attributes do not support complex content (mixed C# and markup)

In good ol' WPF we would probably use a converter in the binding, so the bound boolean is inverted. Is this a limitation of MatBlazor?

The quick solution I see to this is to do something like:

```
<MatButton Disabled="@IsNotReady">Click me</MatButton>
@code
{
    public bool IsReady { get; set; }
    public bool IsNotReady => !IsReady;
}
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution ended up being very easy: you just need to surround C# code with parenthesis:

```
<MatButton Disabled="@(!IsReady)">Click me</MatButton>
```

Answer (score 3):

When using the @ symbol, you're usually switching from a HTML context, to a C# context.  So when you say something like Disabled="@IsNotReady"  - it works just fine.  The moment you try and do something more complicated, even just a "!" operator, that's enough to be something that needs to be evaluated, and not just a reference to a value.  So Blazor requires you to use @( /* code*/ ) and expects it to evaluate to something it can render as text to the output (html in this case).
Blazor requires a literal, a field, or a property.  So you could create a property such as:

```
private bool isNotReady => !isReady;
```

This might seem pointless, but actually it's far more powerful - you can do a lot of logic that evaluates to a true/false or what ever type you need to present to some child component.  So this could also be argued as being a better separation of concerns.

Your code could therefore read more like this:

```
<MatButton Disabled="@IsNotReady">Click me</MatButton>
```